# Oracle BAM 12c - Organising the rows in data object as per timestamp

Tags: sorting, timestamp, osb, data-objects, oracle-bam

I am using BAM 12.1.3 .I have created a dataobject in BAM Composer. The data object has 10 columns. One of the column is "Transaction_TS".
This data object is being called from my OSB service and I am passing current timestamp in the "Transaction_TS" column.
But the data in the data object is not arranged in ascending/descending timestamp format. They are randomly present.
How do I arrange the data in dataobject based on timestamp. I want the data that gets in the dataobject to be sorted in order.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can sort your data on BAM is through Business Views, in Properties menu you have the option Data.

In this case I was using a Pie Business View that use a Group SQL Query:

[image]

You don't have the option of sorting directly on Data Object.